# Why wamp server is running on my computer?

Tags: php

I have first all install the Visual studio 2008 on my computer and after that wamp server. I was try to start wamp server but it can start it shows error. please help me what can i do?

Comment: what you can do is describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: Always when reporting a problem, never, *ever*, forget the three crucial statements: What happened? What was supposed to happen? What have you done so far to fix it? You fail at all three, at least post the error message given by Wamp.

Answer (score 2):

Since your IIS server is also running on port 80 and wamp server also tries to run on port 80, your wamp server won't start. Change the port of the wamp server in Apache httpd.conf file to some different port and try starting the wamp server.

Comment: +1 for stating the solution to the most common problem despite *complete* lack of error description.

Answer (score 0):

[See the installation guide on wamp's website.](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) Or try using the [ECWamp](http://www.fileguru.com/ECWamp/info) instead of wamp.